With gnu make, how do you create new source files in the makefile and dynamically add them to compile/link dependency lists?
With gnu make 3.82 how can I get the files created dynamically within a makefile added to a dependencies variable so they get included in the compile & link rules?
If I start off with the following files:
wut.c:
#include "wut2.h"

int main()
{
    wut2();
}

wut.Makefile:
OBJS := wut.o

all : create_new_files wut.elf

create_new_files :
    @ echo "create_new_files"
    echo "void wut2(void) {}\n" > wut2.c
    echo "void wut2(void);" > wut2.h

%.o : %.c
    @ echo "compile"
    @ echo $@
    @ echo $<
    armcc --licretry --licensing=flex --cpu=Cortex-M0 -c -o $@ $<

wut.elf : $(OBJS)
    @ echo "link"
    @ echo $(OBJS)
    armlink --licretry --licensing=flex -o wut.elf $(OBJS) 

clean :
    rm wut2*
    rm *.o 

I get the following output:
$ make -f wut.Makefile
create_new_files
echo "void wut2(void) {}\n" > wut2.c
echo "void wut2(void);" > wut2.h
compile
wut.o
wut.c
armcc --licretry --licensing=flex --cpu=Cortex-M0 -c -o wut.o wut.c
link
wut.o
armlink --licretry --licensing=flex -o wut.elf wut.o
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol wut2 (referred from wut.o).
Finished: 0 information, 0 warning and 1 error messages.
make: *** [wut.elf] Error 1


Do not modify the question into a different one after you have already received answers. I rolled that back.  If you find that you have asked a different question than you meant to do, then you are welcome to ask a new question.

Side note: if you don't know what files you want to build prior to performing the build, then you may be looking for a script instead of make.  Or a scripted build stage before make.


With gnu make 3.82 how can I get the files created dynamically within a makefile added to a dependencies variable so they get included in the compile & link rules?

What variable?  make does not require any use whatever of variables.  They can be a convenience, but make does require you to use variables to convey information to it.  The only variable in your original makefile is OBJS, its value does not necessarily require modification for your purposes, and you could easily do without it in this case. Perhaps you are confusing rule targets with variables?
Anyway, as a general principle, any file you want make to build for you should be the target of a rule that tells make how to build it.  For example,
wut2.c:
        echo "void wut2(void) {}" > $@

With such a rule in place, make can figure out how to build wut2.o from nothing, by first applying the above rule, and then applying your %o: %c pattern rule.
Of course, you also need to tell make that it needs to build wut2.o.  You can do that in this case by adding it to your OBJS variable (which will be effective simply because of how you use that variable in your makefile, to designate prerequisites of wut.elf).
And that brings us to a second general principle: the rule for each target should list all the target's prerequisites that belong to the project, especially including built ones.  In particular, since your wut.o depends on wut2.h, which is a built file, the rule for building the former should designate the latter among its prerequisites.  That makes wut.o somewhat unsuited for building according to your pattern rule, so it should probably have its own rule.
Remember how I said you don't need to use variables?  Again, you don't, but one of the ways they can be a convenience is to mediate the behavior of makes built-in rules, via a few variables whose names are built into those rules.  With that, you can often avoid writing your own versions of standard pattern rules, such as %o: %c.
Overall, then, this would serve your particular purposes:
# Makefile

OBJS := wut.o wut2.o

CC := armcc
LICFLAGS := --licretry --licensing=flex
CFLAGS := $(LICFLAGS) --cpu=Cortex-M0

all : wut.elf

wut2.c: Makefile
    echo "void wut2(void) {}" > $@

wut2.h: Makefile
    echo "void wut2(void);" > $@

wut.o: wut.c wut2.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

wut.elf: $(OBJS)
    armlink $(LICFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean :
    rm -f wut2.c wut2.h
    rm -f $(OBJS)

Additional notes:

the introduction of variables CPPFLAGS in the rule for wut.o mirrors the form of GNU make's built in implicit rule for building .o files from .c files.  That variable is intended for C or C++ preprocessor flags, which basically means flags required at compile time but not link time.  You don't have any of those in your makefile now, but you might add one or more later, or they can be specified on the command line.

the CC variable names the C compiler to be used by make's built-in rules, and it is idiomatic to use it in explicit rules as well for consistency between explicit and built-in rules.

the CFLAGS variable is for C compiler flags, which basically means flags that should be used both when compiling C sources and when linking object files into programs.  This is another variable that is meaningful to make's built-in rules.

making wut2.c and wut2.h have the makefile itself as a prerequisite allows the files from a previous build to be reused, provided that the makefile has not changed since they were built.  This is natural because in this case, the makefile itself defines their contents.

opinion and practice vary over whether a clean target should clean all built files (e.g., including wut.elf) or only intermediate ones.  In my experience, however, it is more common for them to clean all built files, and that's what I ordinarily expect.



If you're saying that the create_new_files rule must be invoked before you can know what source files to compile, and that there is no way to know, before running it, what files it will generate, then the only real answer is to either (a) run a sub-make after generating the files, or (b) use make's "remaking makefiles" feature.
You have not provided us with enough information for us to give a full solution; for example, you have not explained how you will be able to detect the files that the create_new_files recipe generates, once it's done generating them.  You also haven't described how make should detect whether create_new_files needs to be run in the first place: is there some source file that will be modified which would cause create_new_files to be run again?
Let's suppose that create_new_files outputs its files with a naming convention of wut[0-9].{c,h}.  Then you could do something like this:
OBJS := wut.o
NEW_OBJS := $(NEW_SRCS:.c=.o)

all : create_new_files

create_new_files :
        @ echo "create_new_files"
        echo "void wut2(void) {}\n" > wut2.c
        echo "void wut2(void);" > wut2.h
        $(MAKE) wut.elf NEW_SRCS="$$(echo wut[0-9].c)"

%.o : %.c
        @ echo "compile"
        @ echo $@
        @ echo $<
        armcc --licretry --licensing=flex --cpu=Cortex-M0 -c -o $@ $<

wut.elf : $(OBJS) $(NEW_OBJS)
        @ echo "link"
        @ echo $(OBJS)
        armlink --licretry --licensing=flex -o wut.elf $(OBJS) 

clean :
        rm wut2*
        rm *.o

if you wanted to use recursive make.
A more reliable way to do it would be to use make's remaking makefiles feature.  To do this you need to generate a makefile snippet that defines the prerequisites.  It would be something like this:
OBJS := wut.o

all : wut.elf

%.o : %.c
        @ echo "compile"
        @ echo $@
        @ echo $<
        armcc --licretry --licensing=flex --cpu=Cortex-M0 -c -o $@ $<

wut.elf : $(OBJS)
        @ echo "link"
        @ echo $(OBJS)
        armlink --licretry --licensing=flex -o wut.elf $(OBJS) 

clean :
        rm wut2*
        rm *.o

include new_files.d

new_files.d :
        @ echo "create $@"
        rm -f $@
        echo "void wut2(void) {}\n" > wut2.c
        echo "void wut2(void);" > wut2.h
        echo "wut.elf: wut2.o" >>$@


The issue arises because the dynamically created wut2.c is not included in the dependencies for your build. GNU Make doesn't automatically update the dependencies for wut.elf after create_new_files creates new files. You need to explicitly include these new files as part of your build process.
Here’s a step-by-step solution:
Generate and include dependencies dynamically: After creating wut2.c, you need to add it to the list of objects and ensure it is compiled.
Update the OBJS variable dynamically: Use a secondary expansion or explicitly update OBJS after create_new_files.
Re-run the dependency step: Add a step to ensure Make re-checks dependencies once the new files are created.
Here’s the updated wut.Makefile:
# Initial object file
OBJS := wut.o

# Target to generate all
all : create_new_files compile_all wut.elf

# Rule to create new files
create_new_files :
    @ echo "Creating new files"
    @ echo "void wut2(void) {}\n" > wut2.c
    @ echo "void wut2(void);" > wut2.h

# Update the OBJS variable dynamically
compile_all : create_new_files
    @ echo "Updating object files"
    @ OBJS="$(OBJS) wut2.o"; \
    echo "compile"; \
    echo $$OBJS; \
    $(MAKE) $(OBJS)

# Rule to compile source files into object files
%.o : %.c
    @ echo "Compiling $<"
    armcc --licretry --licensing=flex --cpu=Cortex-M0 -c -o $@ $<

# Link all object files to create the final executable
wut.elf : $(OBJS)
    @ echo "Linking $(OBJS)"
    armlink --licretry --licensing=flex -o wut.elf $(OBJS)

# Clean up generated files
clean :
    rm -f wut2* wut.elf *.o

Key Changes:
Dynamic Update of OBJS: In compile_all, the OBJS variable is updated to include wut2.o.
Phony Targets: The compile_all step is introduced to ensure dependencies are re-evaluated.
Sequential Dependency Handling: Make ensures create_new_files runs before compiling and linking.
Output of make -f wut.Makefile:
$ make -f wut.Makefile
Creating new files
Updating object files
Compiling wut.c
Compiling wut2.c
Linking wut.o wut2.o


This is a bit Rube Goldberg for built files having known names, as in the OP's example.  It would be better to just create appropriate rules for the files to be built, with appropriate prerequisites.

I updated the problem statement to indicate that the generated files are not known, therefore must be dynamically discovered after being generated.
